Qdrant Azure private cloud API KEY setup setting not found
I recently had deployed qdrant onto a AKS Cluster by following this documentation (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/qdrant-azure/blob/main/Azure-Kubernetes-Svc/README.md) and everything is working as expected. However, I noticed that I do not need to input an API Key to access or edit my database. However, I do not have any idea where I can implement this setting.
I first attempted to create a secret instance within AKS and bind it to the StatefulSet, however, that did not seem to do the trick. And after reading a bunch of official documentations, it seems like the only ways to setup an API KEY is either by creating the cluster on the Qdrant Cloud website or by enabling API KEY in the QdrantClusterSetting.yaml. Both these seeme irrelevant in my current state. Is enabling API Key on AKS possible to achieve? Thanks in advance.

As far as I know, enabling API key via the environment variable works in AKS since Qdrant supports configuring security features like API key authentication both via config files and env variables. You can follow up here- https://github.com/qdrant/qdrant-helm/issues/46 it seems to be similar issue.

To set up Qdrant on AKS with API key authentication enabled,
deploy Qdrant using a StatefulSet
kubectl create secret generic qdrant-api-key-secret --from-literal=api-key=b//ZtUPcPLY2i5ktrqdZ0EUvstHkeezHjAQCK6aamRQ= -n qdrant

Deploy Qdrant with StatefulSet
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: qdrant
  namespace: qdrant
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 6333
      targetPort: 6333
      protocol: TCP
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: qdrant
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: qdrant
  namespace: qdrant
spec:
  serviceName: "qdrant"
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: qdrant
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: qdrant
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: qdrant
        image: qdrant/qdrant:v1.2.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6333
          name: qdrant
        env:
        - name: QDRANT__SERVICE__API_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: qdrant-api-key-secret
              key: api-key
        volumeMounts:
        - name: qdrant-data
          mountPath: /qdrant/storage
      volumes:
      - name: qdrant-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: qdrant-pvc
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: qdrant-pvc
  namespace: qdrant
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi

Expose Qdrant via load balancer
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: qdrant-loadbalancer
  namespace: qdrant
spec:
  selector:
    app: qdrant
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 6333
  type: LoadBalancer


Get the external IP of the Qdrant service
kubectl get service qdrant-loadbalancer -n qdrant


To verify that Qdrant is accessible and API key authentication is working, make an HTTP request to the external IP with your API key
curl -H "API-Key: b//ZtUPcPLY2i5ktrqdZ0EUvstHkeezHjAQCK6aamRQ=" http://4.236.219.119:80


If everything is set up correctly, you'll receive a response from Qdrant similar to below-


Thank you for your response! Just a follow up question though, do you have any idea how to apply autoscaling (E.g., HPA) so that it statefulset will scale up once the PV's storage is almost used up? With the way I have tried, it seem to only be able to use the pod's CPU or memory usage and not the storage space :(

HPA won't help as it only supports scaling based on CPU and memory utilization by default. Try KEDA- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/keda-deploy-add-on-cli checkout the left side column of the doc to explore different aspects of keda. If this is for production setup then using custom metrics with Prometheus and Prometheus Adapter or KEDA should be good.
